# how to use .emacs file to open calendar and diary and split the window Mac OS X

Tags: macos, emacs, calendar

I have a question on how to open the calendar and diary (the whole diary, not the diary just for the current date) in emacs using the .emacs file. How can I fix this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. I tried just typing `(calendar) (diary)` and it says:

```
calendar: can't open calendar file "calendar": No such file or directory (2)
-bash: diary: command not found
```

If it helps, below is my code for my .bash_profile and .emacs file:

.bash_profile:

```
PS1=
date
emacs
```

.emacs:

```
(calendar)
(diary)
```

Comment: Looks like your `.emacs` file is actually called from the shell. Do you have some program `calendar` available in `$PATH`? Could it be that you actually have `.emacs` in `.bash_profile` instead of `emacs`?

Comment: Maybe, you saved your `.emacs` file accidentally as `emacs` and you have `.` in your `$PATH`? (Note, that for security reasons you should not have `.` in your `$PATH`. If you want to call a program in the current directory you should state that explicitly.)